# Java android 10 probleme with create file

Tags: java, android

private boolean checkPermissions() {
    listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

```
int permissionRead = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
int permissionWrite = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (permissionRead != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
if (permissionWrite != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}

if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

and

```
public static void parseBase64ToPDFAndNoOpen(String base64, String cardId) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream os;
    File dwldsPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + File.separator + cardId + ".pdf");
    if (!dwldsPath.exists()) {
        dwldsPath.createNewFile();
        byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64, 0);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dwldsPath, false);
        os.write(pdfAsBytes);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

On android 9 all works corretly but on andorid 10 I have this : java.io.IOException: Permission denied All permissions are granded

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 [prohibits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes) the use of external storage. Use instead [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage).

Scoped storage is the folders inside your app directory

Comment: So what I have to do it ?